# Are there many countries in which a postdoc has a student status?

Tags: postdocs

I didn't know that in some countries a postdoc has a student status. I discovered this in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/180426/88083), with somebody mentioning that apparently this is the norm in Israel. I'm surprised and I'm wondering:

- Is this status common, are there other countries doing this?
- How does it work: is the postdoc registered for a diploma? If not, what is the purpose of their "studies"?
- Does the stipend cover any health or unemployment insurance? What about pension contribution?

Comment: I don’t think it’s correct to say that in Israel a postdoc is considered a student. It may be (and I believe it is the case) that a postdoc is covered by some of the same rules as a student with regards to visas and/or taxation of the postdoc stipend. But anyone you ask will tell you that postdocs are not students, and they are not treated as students by any university. In other words, your question is based on a false premise.

Comment: Your second question reminds me of [Do postdoctoral studies have official certificate?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/19533/17254). For the main question, the comments to [these](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/187231/17254) [questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/29631/17254) mention some locations where postdocs may be considered students in some respects. The comment mentioning Quebec is supported by what's on [McGill's website](https://www.mcgill.ca/gps/postdocs/fellows). Perhaps we have some user familiar with the Quebecois arrangements.

Comment: @DanRomik to me this is confusing: if they are not considered students, why would they be considered as such for official purposes? It's especially strange for visa applications: wouldn't that imply that people are lying on their visa applications?

Comment: @Erwan I don’t know, it’s possible that they are considered as students for visa purposes. But I’m not aware of any other context in which they are considered as students.

Comment: @DanRomik sure, but I find it strange that they are considered as students even only for these purposes. From a European point of view, the PhD is what validates the ability to do research, so to me it's professionally degrading not to recognize that postdocs are professional researchers, even only for official purposes.

Comment: @DanRomik I was a postdoc at two different universities in Israel, and in each case I was given a student card.  For all bureaucratic purposes, postdocs in Israel are considered students.

Answer (score 3):

> is this status common

It depends as it varies from place to place. In some countries, for instance South Africa, [postdocs are technically students](https://www.unisa.ac.za/sites/corporate/default/Colleges/College-of-Graduate-Studies/Research-resources/Postdoctoral-Research-Fellows) 'studying' towards academic 'competencies' without a terminal degree.

> Register for degree/diploma

They are a distinct category within the academic workforce. They are not registered for a terminal qualification. They are a *special hybrid* who are meant to be trained on academic processes even as they, postdocs, 'strive' towards *independence*

> stipends, pensions ...

- In places like South Africa, their stipends/fellowship is non-taxable. It's a package that comes without tax, pension or medical.
- In some other places, like some in Europe, they have a 'job'. For instance, Germany places them on TV-L 13.
- In UK, they take up positions as PDRA (postdoctoral research associate) or Research Fellow with salaries and pensions, which are not tax-exempt.
- In the States as you've alluded, postdocs received fellowship that are not IRS tax-exempt. Those on Visa, will have withholding tax deduction based on their visa category.
- postdocs in Australia, (postdocs fellow), are renumerated and subject to superannuation (pension). They work towards independence [supported by training, development and mentorship](https://unisa.edu.au/about-unisa/working-at-unisa/vacancies/postdoctoral-fellows).
- Argentina, AFAIK, tilt towards classification as a student. Their fellowship are *[seen as scholarship](https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/stipendium/datenbank/en/21148-scholarship-database/?detail=10000300)*.

A common thread across postdocs is: mentored, guided professional, internship, apprenticeship.
By and large, postdocs are not standardised across board. It varies from country to country or region to region.

[Edit]

- India apparently follow the 'employee' categorisation and [tax-deductible](https://www.ncbs.res.in/academic/postdoc-pdfa-faq#:%7E:text=If%20you%20obtain%20an%20independently,it%20is%20not%20inflation%2Dadjusted.).
- US (revisited). Stanford seems to consider postdocs as '[non-degree seeking students](https://postdocs.stanford.edu/policy#:%7E:text=Postdoctoral%20Scholars%20are%20registered%20as,allows%20deferment%20of%20student%20loans.&text=Scholars%20are%20full%2Dtime.)'. NorthEastern on the other hand is not clearcut, kindda [pointing to students](https://webguru.sites.northeastern.edu/postdoctoral-students/#:%7E:text=Postdoctoral%20students%20or%20%E2%80%9Cpost%20docs,careers%20in%20academe%20or%20industry.)
- In Canada, postdocs generally pay tax and contribute to pension. They, PD fellow, can be [employee or non-employee](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/canada-pension-plan-cpp-employment-insurance-ei-rulings/cpp-ei-explained/canada-pension-plan-employment-insurance-explained-4.html). Hence there are [exemption where postdocs are students](https://www.mcgill.ca/gps/postdocs/fellows#:%7E:text=As%20postdoctoral%20status%20is%20a,with%20an%20institution%20or%20organization.). Even with the 'exemption', places like McGill required [non-Canadian postdocs to have work permit](https://www.mcgill.ca/gps/postdocs/international/workpermit)!
  University of British Columbia consider [postdocs as employee or *award recipient*](https://hr.ubc.ca/working-ubc/faculty-titles-ranks-and-descriptions/postdoctoral-fellows#:%7E:text=Appointment%20type&text=Appointments%20as%20a%20Postdoctoral%20Fellow,the%20MD%20or%20DDS%20degree.) depending on how they are recruited.
- Postdocs in Chinese universities are regarded as third-party academia with [temporary work](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/21582440231153054). They are tax-deductible.

Comment: Some postdocs in the US are straight up employees, such as at national labs or companies.

Comment: @JonCuster why are they then considered “postdocs” rather than employees with a term-limited contract?

Comment: Well, my institution has a specific job category for postdocs. It is limited term, but is not the only limited term classification. They are employees with benefits, not a fellowship.

Comment: In some places postdocs can get some student priviledges like a student ID (which grants reduced entry fees for some things), a student ticket for public transport or access to student housing.

Comment: From this list it seems that only a few few countries consider postdocs as students: so far we have South Africa, Argentina and Israel.